# How to remove empty values from array in google docs script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-docs-api

I am trying to print out the values of the array in a google doc. I do get the correct values but it goes on printing out a number of "undefined" values. The simplest way is probably to filter out the undefined values before I print out the array.

Here is the array declaration:

```
var paramArr = Object.keys(e.parameter).reverse();
var tableArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < paramArr.length - 1; i++) {
var tempArr;
var nameSelector = "Company:" + i;
var startDateSelector = "Started:" + i;
var endDateSelector = "Ended:" + i;
var referenceSelector = "Reference:" + i;
var descriptionSelector = "Description:" + i;
tempArr = [e.parameter[nameSelector] + "  ",
           e.parameter[startDateSelector] + " - " + 
           e.parameter[endDateSelector]+ "\n\n" +
           e.parameter[descriptionSelector]   
           ];
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
tempArr = tempArr.filter(function(element){
return element !== undefined;
});
```

Comment: What do you spect?, what are the tests you have done?

Comment: @albert I have edited the Question.

Comment: I noticed you defined your variables (empArr, nameSelector,etc) inside a for loop. Try defining them before the for loop, perhaps at the top part, and see if you still get "undefined".